# additional thread using threading.Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I've been digging around trying to get Timer thread working correctly (start and stop).
Here's a bit of code that i use:

```
def start_thread(self):
   "Starting thread"
    self.thread = threading.Timer(10.0, self.process_running)
    self.thread.start()
```

(process_running is testing if the process is already running, if not it's running it by himself)
doing this didn't call the function over and over again, just once, but when I put the above code at the end of my function (self.process_running) it is running every 10 seconds.
The problem with that is that the thread isn't closing even after I close my application ()
I'm trying to cancel it using @atexit to run a function on exit

```
def stop_thread(self)
   self.thread.cancel()
```

hope you can shed some light on that matter.

Comment: Does it work when you use `@atexit` or does it not? If it does, what is your question?

Comment: It doesn't cancel the thread,  the stop_thread function get called, but even when i close my application, the function keeps running (executing the process again and again)

Comment: OK, a lot of information is missing from your example. What type of application are you running. How do you close it?

Comment: Just for testing i'm trying to run notepad.exe, i want to check if the notepad.exe is running, if it isn't, i want to run it.
and i want to run this test every 10 seconds or so.
as noted above, i'm closing my application using the X button (on windows)

Comment: So, you mean that your Python program is to start notepad once, and then if you close notepad it should not re-open it? Or what application is it that you are exiting?

Comment: The python program has a function inside of it (process_running), that suppose to run every 10 seconds and check whether to run noetpad.exe or not.
After exiting the python program, the function seems to keep running.
I close my python application and notepad.exe, but notepad.exe keeps getting executed, i suppose because the function is still running.